# Civicrm Activities - Scheduling conflicts

Tags: activities, scheduling

CiviCRM  4.6.11, Joomla 3.4.8

So we're using activities to schedule meetings between our clients and our staff.

Our admin assistant selects the date and time, and the staff member that will be meeting with the client and creates the meeting activity. The creation generates an email and sends the notification to the staff. Which is all great.

The issue we have is the creation of conflicting meetings. Is there anything in Civicrm that would notify the activity creator that there is already an activity scheduled for that date /  time for that staff member? Rather than having to look up their activities before making the meeting?

Any help would be appreciated, and please let me know if additional details are needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

" Is there anything in Civicrm that would notify the activity creator that there is already an activity scheduled for that date / time for that staff member?"

No there is nothing in CiviCRM that can do this currently.

For anyone using Drupal (I realise this user is on Joomla) then you could make a Views Calendar of Events and that could be used to view existing meetings, including filtering by contact.